# Translating InfluxDB query to PromQL

Tags: influxdb, promql, influxql

I am trying to rewrite a query from InfluxDB Query to PromQL:

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative("wait_time_ms", 1s) FROM "sqlserver_waitstats" WHERE ("sql_instance" =~ /^$InstanceName$/) AND ("wait_type" =~ /HADR/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "wait_type"
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score -1):

The corresponding PromQL query should look like the following:

```
rate(sqlserver_waitstats_wait_time_ms{sql_instance=~"$InstanceName", wait_type=~".*HADR.*"}[5m])
```

It is assumed that the following translation is performed when converting Influx lines to Prometheus metrics:

- `measurement` name is prepended to every `field` name in order to get Prometheus-compatible metric name. For instance, if `measurement` is `sqlserver_waitstats`, while field name is `wait_time_ms`, then the resulting Prometheus metric name would be `sqlserver_waitstats_wait_time_ms` as shown in the query above.
- All the `tags` are translated as is to Prometheus labels. For example,  `sql_instance=foobar` tag from Influx line is translated to `sql_instance="foobar"` Prometheus label.

This is the default translation used by VictoriaMetrics when accepting Influx line protocol data - see [these docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-send-data-from-influxdb-compatible-agents-such-as-telegraf) for details.

Notet that regular expressions in PromQL label matchers are bound to the beginning and the end of label value by default. So there is no need in setting `^` and `$` in the regexp for `sql_instance` above, while we need to add `.*` to `wait_type` regexp, so it matches any value containing `HADR` instead of exact matching.

I'd suggest also reading [PromQL tutorial for beginners](https://medium.com/@valyala/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085) in order to feel better the difference between PromQL and InfluxQL.